# How to received semicolon separated value from GET request in Spring4 MVC

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

At present i am making a **GET** resource using Spring 4 REST full service in which parameters in url are semicolon(;) seperated.
Consider the below as an example:

**http://localhost:9080/myapp/v1/userdetails/{id1;id2}**

My question is how can i receive these parameters id1 and id2 in my controller?

Do let me know if you need anymore details.

Thanks for your suggestion in advance.

Comment: What about Matrix variables? It's seems like what you need. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-matrix-variables

Comment: Hi Alexander Polozov,

Comment: It is giving me error :org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.ClassCastException@2cb5b4a9

Answer (score 1):

why are you gonna do that way ? Use "," and handle with a list for your pathvariable at the end.

http://localhost:9080/myapp/v1/userdetails/{id1,id2}

@GetMapping("/userdetails/{ids}")
public X getUserDetails(@PathVariable("ids") List ids) {
....
}

Answer (score 0):

you can also get all ids by string using path variable.

```
http://localhost:9080/myapp/v1/userdetails/ids=id1,id2
```

then in controller you can use below

```
public void test(@PathVariable("ids") String ids) {
    String splitIds[] = ids.split(",");

    for (String a : splitIds)
        System.out.println(a);
}
```

**Note:** in controller you need to add other annotation to perform perfectly. i have mentioned here only required for this question

Comment: I can not restrict it to use , (comma)instead of ;(semi colon)